# Oracle apex select list and hide values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have scenario that allow the student to choose desire of majors by defining three select list. I have three majors : CS , IT and IS. For example if the student In the first desire he chosen CS from select list then in the second select list the CS major I want it don't appear in the list . For the second select list if he chosen IT then IT don't appear in the third desire where the last select list will contain only IS .

is there any idea how can I do this scenario ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use **Cascading List of Values** and set previous items as "Parent item(s)". Query for every subsequent select list item would remove previously chosen values, e.g.

```
select subject_name d,
       subject_id r
from subjects
where subject_id not in (:P1_FIRST_MAJOR, :P1_SECOND_MAJOR);
```

---

However, why wouldn't you use a **Shuttle** item instead? Offer all subjects and let the student select any of them, simply by moving them from the left to the right side of the shuttle item?

Comment: Yes, I thought from the beginning to use it but would the values show in the same order? if yes how can do it pls

Comment: Using the ORDER BY clause, I presume.

Comment: for example if in the first value was CS I want to store it in the WISH1 column in the table Specialization and for the second if he chooses IT the store it in WISH2  and so on..