# Oracle apex Shuttle list for specific restrictions

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have scenario that allows the student to choose desired majors by defining shuttle  list. I have table called `Specialization` that contains the entities
`WISH1`, `WISH2`, and `WISH3`, and a button called `P3_Submit`.

These are three wishes for three majors (Ex: CS, IT and IS). I want the three majors displays in shuttle list, and force the student (user) to select all three wishes (options on the left) in the order of his preference -- Ex: CS, then IT, then IS meaning the student wishes for CS but if that is not possible he wishes for IT, and then IS is his last preference.

I want to show an error message if the student does not select all threee wishes.
And I want to store all the wishes the student selected in the order he selected them

If anyone can help me in this scenario I’ll be grateful.

Comment: Why is this tagged for MySQL?  Is there actually a MySQL database involved?  It is not obvious to me how this is different from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64191916/oracle-apex-select-list-and-hide-values

Comment: Yes I’m  sorry In the previous question I asked for select list it seems like the same question with little different details

Comment: How does changing to a shuttle from a select list change the question though?  When you implemented exactly the same process of limiting the options in your subsequent shuttle controls that was suggested when you were using select lists, why didn't that solve your problem?

Comment: I think in this question @sersarino is using the same scenario but looking for a different use case where he wants to use a single shuttle list instead of multiple cascading select lists